# Is the time derivative of asset returns expressible as an SDE?

Tags: reference-request, itos-lemma, local-volatility, sde, malliavin-calculus

Consider the following SDE for $(S_t)_{t\geq 0}$ under $\mathbb{Q}$,
\begin{equation}
\mathop{dS_t}=S_t\left(r\mathop{dt}+\sigma(t,S_t)\mathop{dW_t}\right),
\end{equation}
which (in Langevin form) may be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\dot{S}=S_t\left(r+\sigma(t,S_t)\xi(t)\right),
\end{equation}
such that $W_t$ is a wiener process and $\xi(t)$ is white noise with $r$ constant. Is it possible to take the time derivative of the returns of $S_t$, so that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\dot{S}}{S}\right)=\frac{\partial \sigma(S_t,t)}{\partial t}\xi(t)+\sigma(S_t,t)\xi'(t),
\end{equation}
where $\xi'(t):=\left(\xi(t+h)-\xi(t)\right)/h$ as $h\rightarrow 0$? The expectation and covariance of $\xi'(t)=\eta(t)$ are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422857/time-derivative-of-white-noise). If so, can $\xi'(t)$ be expressed as an SDE, in terms of $\xi(t)$, since its distribution is also Gaussian? More succinctly, does there exist a Langevin equation ($a$ would intuitively be zero in this case)
\begin{equation}
\frac{dX_t}{dt}=a(X_t,t)+b(X_t,t)\xi(t),
\end{equation}
or its equivalent SDE where $X_t=\dot{S}/S=d(\ln S_t)/dt$?

Note that I am interpreting derivatives in the generalised sense here, since $\xi(t)$ is clearly nowhere differentiable. Also, if this has been discussed before, I would be grateful for a reference. Any help would be much appreciated.

Referring to the comments, there may be an additional $-\sigma(t,S_t)\frac{\partial \sigma(t,S_t)}{\partial t}$ term to add onto (1) when using Itô's lemma. From a historical context, Langevin equations were developed in the context of physics to study particles undergoing Brownian motion and so provide a less rigorous representation of SDEs when compared with Itô's formalism (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181500/relationship-of-sde-in-langevin-equation-form-and-ito-form)).

**Edit:**
Suppose that $\int_0^{t} X_s\mathop{dW_s}=\ln S_t-\ln S_0$ and $\mathop{dX_t}=a_t\mathop{dt}+b_t\mathop{dW_t}$. Then
\begin{align}
X_s&=X_0+\int_0^{s} a_u\mathop{du}+\int_0^{s} b_u\mathop{dW_u},\\
\int_0^{t} X_s\mathop{dW_s}&=\int_0^{t} X_0 \mathop{dW_s} + \int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} a_u\mathop{du}\mathop{dW_s}+\int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} b_u\mathop{dW_u}\mathop{dW_s}.
\end{align}
By Itô's lemma applied to GBM,
\begin{equation}
\ln S_t=\ln S_0+\int_0^{t}\left(r-\frac{\sigma_s^2}{2}\right)\mathop{ds}+\int_0^{t}\sigma_s\mathop{dW_s}.
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
rt-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t}\sigma_s^2\mathop{ds}+\int_0^{t}\sigma_s\mathop{dW_s}=X_0 W_t + \int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} a_u\mathop{du}\mathop{dW_s}+\int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} b_u\mathop{dW_u}\mathop{dW_s}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Isn't $\log S_t$ the return process? So you get $d \log S_t / dt = r + \sigma (t, S_t) \xi(t)$ in your formalism?

Comment: @starovoitovs Applying Ito's lemma with $f(S_t)=\ln S_t$, gives $d\ln S_t=(r-\sigma^2(t,S_t)/2)\mathop{dt}+\sigma(t,S_t)\mathop{dW_t}$. So, as a Langevin equation, $d\ln S_t/dt=r-\sigma^2(t,S_t)/2+\sigma(t,S_t)\xi(t)$. However, under the formalism I have used, your statement is supposedly also correct. It seems there's a contradiction here. The reason I resorted to Langevin equations (used to study the physical brownian motion) was that the question 'What is the second derivative of $\ln S_t$ with respect to time?' seemed better defined. Can this question be answered using Ito's formalism?

Comment: Why do you insist in taking the derivative(s) of things which are not differentiable?

Comment: @nbbo2 Well, whenever we write down a stochastic differential equation we are taking a generalised derivative of a stochastic variable which is nowhere differentiable (think of the usual Wiener process). In the sense of distributions, such derivatives exist.

Comment: starovoitov's suggestion is imho the most satisfactory. White noise is acceptable when someone insists to use it but to take yet another derivative of $\xi$ seems way over the top or calls for fundamental research.

Comment: @KurtG. Is it not intuitive that we can generalise the usual Itô calculus by taking a second derivative of $W_t$ as a first derivative of $\xi$? Also, the concept of describing the time evolution of returns (or the distribution of returns) in a local volatility setting makes sense.

Comment: When you find that intuitive, good luck when making it rigorous. BTW: you could probably also follow Langevin's  more than one hundred years old approach by letting $X$ be the solution of an SDE driven by a BM and defining $\int_0^tX_s\,ds$ to be the return of $S_t\,.$ In Langevin's physics case $X$ was the velocity of a particle and $S_t$ was its position. No white noise needed. The return of $S$ is differentiable.

Comment: @KurtG. So would something like what I have outlined in the recent edit work? I used Ito's formalism to make things easier / hopefully more rigorous. The trouble is isolating expressions for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Glancing quickly at your recent edit you have a differentiable $\ln S_t=\int_0^tX_s\,ds\,.$ So far so good but this contradicts the equation (hard to believe that this follows by Ito's lemma) $\ln S_t= ...\int_0^t\sigma_s\,dW_s\,.$ We know that that is *not differentiable*.

Comment: @KurtG. I was using Ito's lemma with $f(S_t)=\ln S_t$ on GBM $\mathop{dS_t}=S_t(r\mathop{dt}+\sigma_t\mathop{dW_t})$. Perhaps I have to go to higher order and let $X$ be the 'derivative' of the return rather than the return itself?

Comment: By now it should be clear that you can't have everything: GBM $S_t$ and differentiable return. Start with $X$ solving your favourite SDE and build the return of $S$ only from that by integrating.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. To clarify, my question is based on describing the evolution of returns under GBM. Would integrating with respect to brownian motion s.t. $\int_0^{t} X_s\mathop{dW_s}=\ln S_t-\ln S_0$ avoid contradiction (replacing $\mathop{ds}$ with $\mathop{dW_s}$ where necessary)? 

I think I might have mistakenly conflated differentiability with my main question here. I don't particularly care whether or not returns are differentiable.

Comment: Back to square one (literaly): the first comment by starovoitovs gave *the* evolution equation for *the* return under GBM.

Comment: By evolution of returns $X_t$, I mean an SDE $\mathop{dX_t}=...$ (just like how the *evolution* of a stock price is given as $\mathop{dS_t}=...$)

Comment: The problem is how it is natural to intuit returns $X_t$ as the change in $\ln S_t$ with respect to time when, however, we can not formally differentiate $\ln S_t$ or $X_t$ w.r.t time. This extends to deriving the *evolution* equation (in the sense of $\mathop{dX_t}=...$)